# Plot a dataframe of times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Hi I want to use a dataframe of times which are in the format hh:mm as the xticks of a figure.

Just to represent what I'm doing I have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

#locate series to plot

df = pd.read_excel('Excel_file', header=None)
df1 = df.iloc[71:128, 3]
df2 = df.iloc[71:128, 0]

#Plot df2 on the x-axis and df1 on the y-axis

plt.plot(df2, df1)
plt.xticks(df2)
plt.show()
```

which gives me the (full) error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Alessio/PycharmProjects/PeakAutomation/graphs.py", line 14, in <module>
    plt.xticks(df2)
  File "C:\Users\Alessio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 1483, in xticks
    locs = ax.set_xticks(ticks)
  File "C:\Users\Alessio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 400, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alessio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3306, in set_xticks
    ret = self.xaxis.set_ticks(ticks, minor=minor)
  File "C:\Users\Alessio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\deprecation.py", line 400, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alessio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1765, in set_ticks
    self.set_view_interval(min(ticks), max(ticks))
  File "C:\Users\Alessio\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 1902, in setter
    setter(self, min(vmin, vmax, oldmin), max(vmin, vmax, oldmax),
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'datetime.time'
```

How can I plot df2 as the x-axis values?

When I dont try to change the xticks, I get this:
[image: Current graph output]

Which is fine, but I want to have the x-values to be those from the dataFrame (df2)

Thanks

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Comment: Apologies, hopefully my edits have made it a bit clearer?